# Android lower API level unable to load bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I'm using two Android phones for testing and the thing I'm trying to do is displaying an image (bitmap) as an ImageView right after taking / selecting the picture from the gallery and camera.

It is working fine for higher API level phones like LG-Nexus 5 (API Level 24) or Galaxy Note 4 (Level 23), but it is not working for the XiaoMi MI 3W (API Level 19) as there will only be a blank white displayed as the ImageView right after taking pictures and selecting images.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri image = imageUri;
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(image, null);
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

                Bitmap bitmap;

                String path = image.getPath();

                try {
                    bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                            .getBitmap(cr, image);
                    bitmap = modifyOrientation(bitmap, path);

                    String decoded = MDSUtilities.encodeBitmapToBase64(bitmap, true);

                    binding.imageProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    Blurry.with(this).from(bitmap).into(binding.profileBannerImage);

                    UploadRequest request = new UploadRequest(decoded);

                    ApiProvider.getSharedInstance().uploadProfileImage(this, request, new ApiProvider.APICompletionGeneral() {
                        @Override
                        public void OnSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void OnFailure(Boolean handleError, Integer statusCode, String errorMessage) {

                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2 :
            if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                Bitmap bitmap;
                String path = getPath(this, uri);

                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, uri);
                    bitmap = modifyOrientation(bitmap, path);
                    binding.imageProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    Blurry.with(this).from(bitmap).into(binding.profileBannerImage);

                    UploadRequest request = new UploadRequest(MDSUtilities.encodeBitmapToBase64(bitmap, true));

                    ApiProvider.getSharedInstance().uploadProfileImage(this, request, new ApiProvider.APICompletionGeneral() {
                        @Override
                        public void OnSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void OnFailure(Boolean handleError, Integer statusCode, String errorMessage) {

                        }
                    });

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I'm also using data binding and the MVVM architecture, and I'm also using a third party library to display a blurry view (works fine on level 23 and 24 but not 19).

I haven't tested on other phones other than these 3 phones.

Is there a way for this? I can't seem to find the solution anywhere online regarding about the API level and setting the bitmap.
Or are API levels not the factor?

Comment: Is the blurred image being shown correctly?

Comment: For the Lower API level phone, no, both the profile image and the banner are showing white